# Regarding Lax-Milgram theorem (Operator theory)

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem, sesquilinear-forms

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $B\colon H\times H\to C$ a sesquilinear form.
Assume that there's $0 \leq M <\infty$ such that for all $x,y\in H$:
$|B(x,y)| \leq M\|x\| \|y\|$.

A.  Show that there is a single $T\in B(H)$  such that for every $x,y\in H$:
$B(x,y)=(x,Ty)$ and $T$ satisfies $\|T\|\leq M$.

B.  Starting from this part, assume that there's $0< m<\infty$ such that for every $x,y\in H$:
$B(x,x)\geq m\|x\|^2$.
Show that $T$ is injective.

C. Show that $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is dense in $H$.

D. Show that $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is closed in the following way:
$\forall x\in H$ by the inequality
$m\|x\|^2\leq B(x,x)=(x,Tx)$ deduce that $m\|x\|\leq \|Tx\|$, and use a suitable theorem regarding these operators.
Another approach, see what you'll get if $(Tx_n)$ is a Cauchy series in $H$.

E. Deduce that $T$ is invertible and $\|T^{-1}\| \leq m^{-1}$.

In A, I know that we need to rewrite the given form, but did not het the result mentioned.

B: using the information given in this part we have, $(x,Tx)=B(x,x)\geq m\|x\|^2$, now assume that $Tx=0$ so we have
$0=(x,0)\geq m\|x\|^2\geq 0$ (since $m>0$),
So $x$ must be $0$.

C: by contradiction, assume that $\mathrm{Im}(T)=TH \subset H$ and there is $u\in H\setminus TX$, then by the Hahn banach theorem/claim there exists a linear bounded functional  $x^*\neq 0 \in H^*$ such that $x^*(TH)=0$ so $T^*x^*H=0$ ,therefore $T^*x^*=0$ then $x^*=0$ in contradiction.

D. $m\|x\|^2\leq B(x,x)=(x,Tx)\leq \|x\| \|Tx\|$, so $m\|x\|\leq \|Tx\|$.
Now, using a theorem about an operator $T$ that satisfies this inequality, we get that $T$ has a close range.
How to do this part in the other suggested method?

E: From parts B we have that $T$ is injective and from C and D, we got that $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is closed and dense in $H$ and therefore $T$ is surjective.
In A we have that $T\in B(H)$, so by the inverse bounded theorem we deduce that $T$ has a bounded inverse.

Can you please tell me how to do part A, and the remaining part in E, and if what I did is okay.

Thanks

Comment: Mathjax tip: Instead of `$||x||$` $\to||x||$ you may want to use `$\|x\|$` $\to \|x\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

For part A, use the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#Riesz_representation_theorem).  For any given $\ y\in H\ $ the function $\ \phi_y:H\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\ $ defined by
$$
\phi_y(x)=B(x,y)
$$
is a bounded linear functional on $\ H\ $ $\big($since $\ \big|\phi_y(x)\big|\le M\|y\|\|x\| $ for all $\ x\in H\ \big)$. Therefore, by the Riesz representation theorem, there exists a unique $\ z_y\in H\ $ such that
\begin{align}
\phi_y(x)&=\big(x,z_y\big)\\
&=B(x,y)
\end{align}
for all $\ x\in H\ $.  Define $\ T:H\rightarrow H\ $ by putting $\ Ty=z_y\ $.  Use the identity and inequality
$$
(x,Ty)=B(x,y)\le M\|x\|\|y\|\ ,
$$
and the sesquilinearity of $\ B\ $ and $\ (.,.)\ $ ,to establish that $\ T\in B(H)\ $ with $\ \|T\|\le M\ $.

For the remaining part of E $\big(\ \big\|T^{-1}\big\|\le m^{-1}\ \big)$, put $\ x=T^{-1}y\ $ in the inequality $\ m\|x\|\le \|Tx\|\ $ you've already established in part D.

Comment: Thanks! @lonza leggiera Are the other parts I accomplished fine?

Comment: In the remining part of E, tried whay you mentioned, i got: $m\|T^{-1}y\|\leq \|TT^{-1}y\|\leq \|TT^{-1}\|||y||=||y||$ so it gives $m||T^{-1}y||\leq ||y||$ how this can lead to the result?

Comment: You've got $\ \big\|T^{-1}y\big\|\le m^{-1}\|y\|\ $ for *all* $\ y\in H\ $. Divide through by $\ \|y\|\ $ and take the supremum over $\ y\ne0\ $. The other parts looked fine to me, although I only skimmed over them.